# Why do I  get garbled characters？

Tags: r, parsing, encode

Why do I  get garbled characters in parse a web?

I have used `encoding="big-5\\IGNORE"`to get the normal character, but it doesn't work.

```
require(XML)
url="http://www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"
options(encoding="big-5")
data=htmlParse(url,isURL=TRUE,encoding="big-5\\IGNORE")
tdata=xpathApply(data,"//table[@class='table_grey_border']")
stock <- readHTMLTable(tdata[[1]], header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

[image]

How should I  revise my code to change the garbled characters  into normal?

[image]

@MartinMorgan (below) suggested using

`htmlParse(url,isURL=TRUE,encoding="big-5")`

Here is an example of what is going on:

```
require(XML)
url="http://www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"
options(encoding="big-5")
data=htmlParse(url,isURL=TRUE,encoding="big-5")
tdata=xpathApply(data,"//table[@class='table_grey_border']")
stock <- readHTMLTable(tdata[[1]], header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
stock
```

[image]

The total records should be 1335. In the case above it is 309 - many records appear to have been lost

This is a complicated problem. There are a number of issues:

- A Badly-formed html file

The web is not a standard web, not well formed html file,let me prove my point.
please run :

```
url="http://www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"
txt=download.file(url,destfile="stockbig-5",quiet = TRUE)
```

How about to open the downloaded file `stockbig-5`wiht firefox?
[image]

- Iconv function bug in R
  if a html file is well formed,you can use

  data=readLines(file)
  datachange=iconv(data,from="source encode",to="target encode\IGNORE")

when a html file is not well formed,you can do that way ,in this example,
please run ,

```
data=readLines(stockbig-5)
```

An error will occur.

```
1: In readLines("stockbig-5") :  
  invalid input found on input connection 'stockbig-5'
```

You can't use iconv function in R to change encode in bad formed html file.

You can, however do this in shell

Comment: XML contains `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5" />`. Why are you trying to parse it as it has `bg2312` charset?

Comment: I had a try with big-5,still garbled character.

Comment: Output from `sessionInfo()` would be a useful addition to the question please.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i486-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.9-4

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it myself for one night,hard time.
System:debian6(locale utf-8)+R2.15(locale  utf-8)+gnome terminal(locale utf-8).
Here is the code:

```
require(XML)
url="http://www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"
txt=download.file(url,destfile="stockbig-5",quiet = TRUE)
system('iconv -f big-5  -t  UTF-8//IGNORE    stockbig-5  > stockutf-8')
data=htmlParse("stockutf-8",isURL=FALSE,encoding="utf-8\\IGNORE")
tdata=xpathApply(data,"//table[@class='table_grey_border']")
stock <- readHTMLTable(tdata[[1]], header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
stock
```

[image]

I want my code more elegant ,the shell command in R code is ugly maybe,

system('iconv -f big5  -t  UTF-8//IGNORE    stockgb2312  > stockutf-8')

i made tries to replace it with pure R code ,failed ,how can replace it in pure R code?
you can duplicate the result in your computer with the code.
half done,half success,continue to try.

Comment: This `data=htmlParse(url, isURL=TRUE, encoding="big5")` (no separate file download, just big5 encoding) worked for me with similar `sessionInfo()`

Comment: if you use  `data=htmlParse(url, isURL=TRUE, encoding="big5")`,you lose many records,you can get part of company,many of them lost